# Verification required on identification of supremum and infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Are the following identifications correct? I am particularly unsure about *(b)*.

*(a)*. $\left\{m/n : m,n\in\mathbf{N}\text{ with }m<n\right\}$

*Solution.* Letting $A$ denote the above set, $\inf A=0$ and $\sup A = 1$.

*(b)*. $\left\{(-1)^m/n : m,n\in\mathbf{N}\right\}$

*Solution.* Letting $B$ denote the above set, $\inf B=0$ and  $\sup B = 1$

*(c)*. $\left\{n/(3n+1) : n\in\mathbf{N}\right\}$

*Solution.* Letting $C$ denote the above set, $\inf C = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\sup C = \frac{1}{3}$.

*(d)*. $\left\{m/(m+n) : m,n\in\mathbf{N}\right\}$

*Solution.* Letting $D$ denote the above set, $\inf D = 0$ and $\sup D = 1$.

Comment: For b), what about $m=n=1$?

Comment: @Atbey here $\mathbf{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$

Comment: My bad, thought about integers.

Comment: @Arthur ok so my $\inf B$ is wrong but then is  $\inf B=-1$? How can i be sure?

Comment: @AtifFarooq Since $-1\in B$ and $$\frac{(-1)^m}n\geqslant-\frac1n\geqslant-1,\quad ∀m,n\in\mathbb N_+,$$then $\inf B=-1$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Thankyou very much for your remark. Should the assume that the other parts are correct?

Comment: @AtifFarooq Yes, the rest answers are correct. Good job :)